# how to stop both sessions being run both 'admin' and 'user'

Tags: php

I cannot get the `$_SESSION` to just create either the `user` or `admin` session.

This is the contents of the accounts file:

`User||1234||user
     admin||1234||admin`

Start of the code:

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php
$username = $_POST['username']; 
$password = $_POST['password'];
$level;
$date = date("d.m.Y");`
```

Current code:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
    $file = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents( "Users/accounts.txt" ));
    $auth = false;

foreach( $file as $line ) {
    list($username, $password, $level) = explode("||", $line);
    if ($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password) {
         $auth = true;
         break;
    }
}

 if($auth) {
    echo "Login successfull!";
    $data = "Login successfull" . "\t" . "Username: " . $_POST['username'] . " Password: " . $_POST['password'] . " Level: " . $level . " Date: " . $date . "\r\n";
    file_put_contents('Users/logs.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);

    if($level = 'admin') {
        $_SESSION['admin']=$username;
        header('location: check.php');  
    }
    if($level = 'user') {
        $_SESSION['user']=$username;
        header('location: check.php');  
    }
} 
else {
    echo "Invalid username or password";

    $data = "invalid login" . "\t" . "Username: " . $_POST['username'] . " Password: " . $_POST['password'] . " Level: " . $level . " Date: " . $date . "\r\n";

    file_put_contents('Users/logs.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
?>

Current form:

<form method="post">
<b>Username:</b><br>
<input type="text" name="username" /><br>                
<b>Password:</b><br>
<input type="password" name="password"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="login"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset"/>
</form>`
```

Please help, I've tried to change the names of the sessions and other little things but I cannot get it to stop doing both the session as I am trying to stop certain session from accessing certain pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to read the file line by line then you should do that, when you read the whole file and then try to use `explode` it's very inefficient (and apparently doesn't do what you want).
Do this:

```
$file = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($file) {
  while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
    list($username, $password, $level) = explode("||", $line);
    if ($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password) {
      $auth = true;
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have sorted the not reading both accounts but yours does work too, however I am having the problem that when I would log in as the `User` I will still have access to the `admin session` pages, I know its not that the pages i have aren't coded properly because for some reason the even when logging in as the `User` it will create both sessions of `user` and `admin`. Can you help?

Comment: sorry I didn't notice that, make the following changes
`$level = 'admin'` => `$level == 'admin'` and
`$level = 'user'`=> `$level == 'user'`